# Undefined index in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know there are a lot of related questions regarding the undefined index error in PHP, however I cannot seem to find an answer which helps.

I'm creating a multidimensional array as follows:

```
$types = array ();
while ( current ( $tokens ) ) {
    $key = key ( $tokens );
    array_push ( $types, array (
            'type' => $key,
            'frequency' => $tokens [$key],
            'id' => $t_id 
    ) );
    next ( $tokens );
}
```

So now each element in `$types` is an array containing the type, frequency and object id.

After some further processing I also have to add every element in `$types` into an even larger array `$json_index` so this new array would contain the exact kind of arrays as in `$types` but it will be the ***main*** array so to speak (due to the nature of my project):

```
foreach ( $types as $type ) {
            $json_index[] = [$type];                
        }
```

Now I would like to sort this array of associative arrays, `$json_index`, by `'type'`and I try this as follows:

```
$type_arr = array();

foreach ($json_index as $key => $row)
{   
    $type_arr[$key] = $row['type'];
}

$json_index = array_multisort($type, SORT_DESC, $json_index);
```

Unfortunately when `$type_arr[$key] = $row['type'];` is executed it's giving me the following error:

```
Undefined index: type
```

I don't understand, am I creating `$json_index` in an incorrect way? The error is because `'type'` is not being recognised however I do not understand how it is not being defined.

Comment: The way you created it, $row is an array containing a single element, $type. Therefore, $row[0]['type'] should work!

Comment: why you have `$json_index[] = [$type];` instead of `$json_index[] = $type;` ?  and what is the reason for that loop ? why not `$json_index=$types;` ?

Comment: @repptilia Thank you it worked!

@KimAlexander I cannot just do `$json_index = $types` as I have a number of different `$types` arrays to add to `$json_index`, basically I have to update it multiple times.

@samyismyhero `$tokens` is an associative array of word tokens and their respective frequencies